# Retrofit2 + RxJava. Зачем?

Tags: android, rxjava, retrofit2

У меня два вопроса:

1. Зачем использовать RxJava при работе с Retrofit2? Единственная причина что я находил - удобство обработки.
2. Если опустить это преимущество, то так ли нужна RxJava сейчас в мобильной разработке?

Когда я засомневался в необходимости Rx для меня - я начал изучать корутины и они приглянулись намного больше. Стоит ли пропустить Rx или он необходим?

Comment: Rx Вы найдете в огромном множестве старых проектов. Корутины сейчас чаще используются, но только когда речь идет о создании новых проектов. Если Вы учите Андроид "для души", то Вам хватит и одного из двух. Если намерены заняться профессионально - учить придется и то и другое в любом случае. В каком порядке - в целом не важно. Я бы учил то, что сейчас проще идет.